# Calling POST method of wcf rest service using jquery?

Tags: jquery, wcf

My Post method

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Service/UpLoadCarPhoto",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    public string UpLoadCarPhoto(Stream imageFile)
    {

        try
        {
            _db.CarPhotoes.Add(new CarPhoto
            {
                CarPhotoId = 7,
                CarId = 2,
                CarPhoto1 = ReadFully(imageFile)
            });
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return "Photo Saved";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message;
        }

    }
```

My Web Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
          <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        </assemblies>
      </compilation>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="CarHaatDbContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.CarHaatModel.csdl|res://*/Entities.CarHaatModel.ssdl|res://*/Entities.CarHaatModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CarHaatDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <!--<add name="CarHaatDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; 
AttachDbFilename=F:\8-Semester Project\11-20-13\CarHaat\CarHaatWcfService\App_Data\CarHaatDatabase.mdf;
Integrated Security=True; Connect Timeout=30; User Instance=True" />-->
  </connectionStrings>


</configuration>
```

How I am calling this service

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.base64.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


<input type="file" name="UploadImage" id="CarImage"/>
<input type="button" id="uploadImage"/>



<script type="text/javascript">

    var getCarUrl = 'http://localhost:62051/Service/GetCarList';
    var postCarUrl = 'http://localhost:62051/Service/UpLoadCarPhoto';

    $('#uploadImage').click(
    function () {
        var im = $('#CarImage').get(0).files[0];
        alert(im);
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",

            url: postCarUrl,

            data: im,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.status);
            }
        });

            }
    );


</script>
```

I got the following error

```
NS_NOINTERFACE: Component does not have requested interface [nsIDOMBlob.slice]
```

Comment: I've run into something similar... without seeing testing all the code I can't say for sure this is the problem, but putting non string data into data for your ajax can result in that error.  Since your content type is JSON, call JSON.stringify( im ) in data.  MAYBE that's the fix.

Comment: Was that the answer? If so, might I officially answer for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as your content type is JSON, calling `JSON.stringify ( im )` in the data area of your AJAX call should fix this.  This error can occur because of non-string data being passed as the payload of the AJAX.